# A question about a [ModelVisual3D] updating in WPF after I change the AxisAngleRotation3D value

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm a newer to use WPF. I display a 3D object in my winform software. Through the elementHost controls, I can correctly load the object. But when I invoked a test-function to rotate the object, I found the value changed. I have interrupted the software to check. But the object showed in UI didn't update. How could I accomplish the function that UI interface when AxisAngleRotation3D changed?

Below is the simplified test code. First code block is model.xaml.

```
<ModelVisual3D x:Name="World">
                    <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                        <Transform3DGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform3D ScaleZ="1.0" ScaleY="1.0" ScaleX="1.0"/>
                            <RotateTransform3D d:EulerAngles="90.806,-49.429,-19.335" >
                                <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="myAxis" Axis="0,1,0" Angle="10"/>
                                </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            </RotateTransform3D>
                        </Transform3DGroup>
                    <ModelVisual3D x:Name="DefaultGroup">
                   <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                   I omit this part which is not related to the topic.
                   </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                   </ModelVisual3D>
</ModelVisual3D>
```

The second code block is model.xaml.cs.

```
 public void rotate3D()
        {
            Vector3D vector = new Vector3D(0,1,1);
            double angle = 100;
            AxisAngleRotation3D axisAngleRotation3D = new AxisAngleRotation3D(vector, angle);
            myAxis = axisAngleRotation3D;
        }
```

The third code block is a function that invoked by the user, such as button clicked.

```
        private void ControlRotateModel()
        {

            try
                {
                    ((model)elementHost.Child).rotate3D();
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     //
                }

        }
```

Comment: not a newer,  just a noob :)

Comment: WinForms not really suited for this kind of task. If you're able; I would suggest to use a WPF only solution.

Comment: Hello! Can you try `myAxis.Axis = vector; myAxis.Angle = angle;` instead of assigning a new object to `myAxis`?

Comment: That's a good idea. But I just want to add a simple 3D rotate display function in the winform-based software

Comment: RE: Corentin Pane
I have tried but not work.

Comment: Does there exist some render functions after the property value changed?

Comment: Does your method work when not embedded inside an `ElementHost`? That would be a start.

Comment: I added the MessageBox.Show() to the `rotate3D()`. And test shows the method works.